# Laravel login error

Tags: authentication

I'm quite a newbie in laravel. I looked up a video tutorial to set up registration and login. Registration works perfectly, but I'm having trouble with login. At first it worked perfectly, but then I noticed, that that doesnt matter with which user do I log in, it's always the same user, who is logen in. But now, out of nowhere, i can't even log in, it throws an error:

> "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given"

I think that I know where the mistake is, but I do not think that my skills are that advanced to solve it.
Here is my UserController code:

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('user.login', array('title'=>'Login'));
}
    public function userlogin()
{
            $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('UserName'=>'required|alpha_num',
                                                            'Password'=>'required'));
            if($validate->fails()){
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput(Input::get());                   
            }
            else{
                $checkuser=UserModel::login(input::all());
                if($checkuser[0]){
                    Auth::login(User::find(1));
                    return Redirect::to('users');
                }
                else{
                    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(array('loginerror'=>$checkuser[1]))
                                           ->withInput(Input::get());
                }
            }
}
```

here is my UserModel code:

```
    public static function login($values){
    $pickPassword=DB::table('users')->where('name', '=', $values['UserName'])->pluck('password');
    if(!$pickPassword){
        return array(false, "User not found!");
    }
    else{
        $checkPassword=Hash::check($values['Password'],$pickPassword);
        if($checkPassword){return array(true);}
        else {return array(false, "Wrong password");}
    }
}
```

Here is my user table:

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('users', function($table)
        {
            // Autoincrement+INT+primary key (Laravel requires)
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 100); // VARCHAR 100
            $table->string('email'); // VARCHAR 255
            $table->string('password', 60); // VARCHAR 60
            $table->text('about'); // TEXT 64K
            // Integer + unsigned 4Bytes
            $table->integer('favorite')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps(); // timestamps (Laravel requires)
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
        Schema::drop('users');
}
```

I think the problem is somewhere UserController with Auth::login, but not really sure, it worked perfectly a while ago...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Login & Registration with Error Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738641/laravel-login-registration-with-error-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::login(User::find(1));
```

with this line, you are doing a login for the first user all the time

in this block:

```
        else{
            $checkuser=UserModel::login(input::all());
            if($checkuser[0]){
                Auth::login(User::find(1));
                return Redirect::to('users');
```

you need to pass the arguments given from your login form to auth. For example:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
```

This is what you are actually doing, login a user manually:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually

SIDENOTE:

[The laravel documentation on Authentication is amazing, go check it out!](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security)

Comment: Thanks, but how does the Auth::attempt know where to lookfor the 'email' and 'password'? Is it pointed out in some other file? maybe my database names does not mach.

Comment: Have a look at your app/config/auth.php file, there you can name the used model and table